# How to access child model from parent model in Python

Tags: django, django-3.0

I am trying to get data from child model through the parent model, I don't know if it possible or there is a way of doing it, and I want to know how to implement the formset concept in this context  , I would be grateful for any solution

models.py

```
class Client_Data(models.Model):
     RC = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     Raison_social = models.CharField(max_length=254)
     NIF = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
     AI = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
     NIS = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
     Banque = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
     CB = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     adresse = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Contact(models.Model):
     client = models.ForeignKey(Client_Data,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     Nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     Tel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
     contact_type = models.CharField(default='Client_contact',max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
def save_client_form(request, form,Contact_form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid() and Contact_form.is_valid():
            client = form.save()
            contact = Contact_form.save(commit=False)
            contact.client = client
            contact.save()
            form.save()
            Contact_form.save()

            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Client_Data.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('Client_Section/partial_client_c.html', {
                'client': books
            })
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            print(Contact_form.errors)
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form,'contact_form':Contact_form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def client_update(request,slug):
    book = get_object_or_404(Client_Data, slug=slug)
    contact = Contact.objects.select_related().filter(client=book.id)
    print(contact)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=book)
        contact_form = Contact_Form(request.POST, instance=contact)
    else:
        form = ClientForm(instance=book)
        contact_form = Contact_Form(instance=contact)
    return save_client_form(request, form,contact_form ,'Client_Section/partial_client_update.html')
```

Comment: There can be many `Contact` objects for each `Client_Data`, do you want a form for each? At the moment you're passing a queryset to your `Contact_Form` which is not correct

Comment: okay, what do you suggest for the situation?

Comment: It depends on what outcome you want. Do you want a form for each contact?

Comment: let's say so, a form for each contact

Comment: You should look into formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: okay thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you may simply do it this way:

```
contact = Contact.objects.select_related().filter(client=book.id)
addresse = contact.client.addresse
```

Comment: not working AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: This is because you get Queryset when you use filter. If you use get, then you may be fine ```contact = Contact.objects.get(client=book.id) and then addresse = contact.client.addresse

Comment: another error : Client_Section.models.Contact.DoesNotExist: Contact matching query does not exist.

Comment: Try this: contact, _ = Contact.objects.get_or_create(client=book.id) and then id = contect.client.id

Answer (score 0):

in you view.py

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def client_update(request, slug):
    context = {}
    book = get_object_or_404(Client_Data, slug=slug)
    formset = inlineformset_factory(Client_Data, Contact, form=Contact_Form )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=book)
        contactforms = formset(request.POST, prefix='contactformset', instance=book)
        context['form'] = form
        context['contactforms'] = contactforms
        if contactforms.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            contactforms.save()
            return HttpResponse("your data saved")
        else:
            return render(request, 'Client_Section/partial_client_update.html', context)
    else:
        form = ClientForm(instance=book)
        contactforms = formset(prefix='contactformset', instance=book)
        context['form'] = form
        context['contactforms'] = contactforms
        return render(request, 'Client_Section/partial_client_update.html', context)
```

in partial_client_update.html

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form}}
    <hr>
    {% formset in contactforms %}
    {{formset }}
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}

   <button type="submit ">update</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: i have this error now : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: in you views.py 

client_update function return save_client_form.
what is save_client_form? is this a function you wrote.

by the way, i have given an example of inlineformset which is very easy.
if you can try this.

Comment: problem in you views is here

contact_form = Contact_Form(instance=contact)

instance take single objects, and here you passed contact which is queryset.
here is a tutorial on youtube for your kind of approch.
where you have to use for loop for every contact object form.
https://youtu.be/60iSm9Bzm0c